# ASP.NET Core 2.1: Razor UI as Class Library

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

I try to create a Razor page class library project but I can not find the equivalent template. I installed the .NET Core 2.1 SDK (v2.1.300-rc1). According to this article http://www.talkingdotnet.com/asp-net-core-2-1-razor-ui-as-class-library/ it is enough in order to be able to create a Razor page class library project. Do I miss something?

Is there a way to install the template manually?

The versions of Visual Studio that I have installed are Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.7.3 and Microsft Visual Studio Community 2017 Preview Version 15.8.0 Preview 2.0

Comment: Any reason you are using the release candidate instead of the final release?

Comment: Thank you very much. I installed the final release and now I can see the Razor Class Library Template.